# How to remove file extension from the filename?

Tags: batch-file

I wrote some simple batch file that converts any audio/video files to .ogg (audio) format. For example music off youtube which is in .flv format. Here's the script:

```
set ogg_rate=1.3
set source_dir=f:\music
set dest_dir=f:\music\out
set my_temp=f:\temp

Rem Go to source dir
cd /d %source_dir%
for %%f in (*.*) do (

Rem Extract audio from avi file using ffmpeg
c:\encode\ffmpeg.exe -i "%source_dir%\%%f" "%my_temp%\%%f.wav"

rem Encode the audio with OGG encoder using 1.3 quality setting
cd /d %my_temp%
c:\encode\oggenc2.exe -q %ogg_rate% -o "%dest_dir%\%%f.ogg" "%my_temp%\%%f.wav"

rem delete all temp files
cd /d %my_temp%
del *.* /q
)
```

It works file, but I cannot figure out how to remove the unnecessary extension.

For example, if the input file is `file.flv` then after converting to wave it will be `file.flv.wav`, then after converting it to `.ogg` it will be `file.flv.ogg`.

How to get the `file.ogg` (without `.flv`)

BTW: instead of `.flv` it can be `.mp4`, `.avi` or another extension.

Answer (score 2):

In your `for` statement, try using `%%~nf` instead of `%%f`. [For statements in batch files](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) have a lot of substitution options you can utilize:

```
for   %%R in (*.*) do (
    @echo %%~nR 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but ,strangly, %%~nf doesn't work - it gives "unexpected at this time" I've read in the link you provided that it should take the filename only w/o the extension. Not sure why it doesn't work though..

Comment: OK, I got it. I need to use %%~nf not everywhere, but where i want filename only. like this:    for %%f in (*.*) do (
c:\encode\ffmpeg.exe -i "%source_dir%\%%f" "%my_temp%\%%~nf.wav"

cd /d %my_temp%
c:\encode\oggenc2.exe -q %ogg_rate% -o "%dest_dir%\%%~nf.ogg" "%my_temp%\%%~nf.wav"
)

Comment: if you ever need a handy list of such things, try `for /?`

Comment: I think you're putting the %%~nf in the for statement directly. I updated my answer with an example for you.